# Is this part correct in the "When should I propose a tag synonym?", can I see an example?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, privileges-page

I recently read the [Create Tag Synonyms privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), and found this:

> When should I propose a tag synonym?
>
> Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged **with the wrong or
>   incorrect tag** -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing...

I can't imagine an example of the bold text, I have only seen tag synonyms that were created for the sole purpose of *"multiple tags that mean the same thing"*.

Can I see an example? I am a bit skeptic that there can actually exist *valid* examples, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I assumed it meant "very common typos", e.g. "toyps" => "typos"

Comment: @BenBrocka I don't think tags with typos should exist, and much less synonimized (even if they are heavily misspelled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an incorrect, or wrong tag would mean using [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7) instead of [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7), or [drupla-view](/questions/tagged/drupla-view) instead of [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views).

Comment: the second example looks like _multiple tags that mean the same thing_, but the first example looks like it might be what they were trying to say. +1 and I will wait to see if everyone agrees and then accept

Comment: The second example was an example of typo: The name of the CMS is Drupal, not Drupla. `:)`

Comment: @ki didn't notice. But well, those tags need to be destroyed not synonimized.

Comment: It depends: If there are 150 questions using [tag:drupal7], I would merge it with [tag:drupal-7]; if there is the probability users keep using [tag:drupal7], then I would make it a synonym of the correct tag. It is just a matter of how much times the wrong tag is being used, as editing a question to fix a typo in a tag should IMO be avoided, when possible. The reason for making a tag a synonym is that some users add tags uncaring of the suggestions made when entering a tag. That is the only explanation I have for the renames reported in the tag synonyms page, and which increase for some tags.