# I just got old notifications again

Tags: bug, notifications

Today I got 4 *old* notifications (2 red, 2 blue) that were already marked as seen and correctly removed. The first time I saw them was on Oct 26 and then today (Oct 30).

I have visited the site every day multiple times and it is *impossible* I missed the notifications (I can guarantee they were gone and then reincarnated).

One of the notifications was telling me about my new *create tag synonyms* privilege, I clicked it and read the page, I even [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152718/179635) to clarify some doubts about the page. So there is absolutely zero chance I missed the notifications.

Additional information:

- my inbox does NOT contain duplicate entries.
- the date of the *red* notifications is 27 Oct, I assume it is the same with the *blue* notifications, but I couldn't get the date no matter where I hovered my mouse.

Comment: I agree with this. This happens sometimes. But after few times, the inbox get refreshed with the latest one.

Comment: Have you watched the news from New York this morning?  Your inbox got blown to Oregon.